# colour terminal text effects with Python

Tags: python, colors

I'm trying to implement colour cycling on my text in Python, ie i want it to cycle through the colour of every character typed (amongst other effects) My progress so far has been hacked together from an [ansi colour recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/574451/) improvement suggestions welcomed.

I was also vaguely aware of, but never used: [termcolor](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/termcolor), [colorama](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama), [curses](http://docs.python.org/howto/curses.html)

during the hack i managed to make the attributes not work (ie reverse blink etc) and its not perfect probably mainly because I dont understand these lines properly:

```
cmd.append(format % (colours[tmpword]+fgoffset))

c=format % attrs[tmpword] if tmpword in attrs else None
```

if anyone can clarify that a bit, I would appreciate it. this runs and does something, but its not quite there. I changed the code so instead of having to separate colour commands from your string you can include them.

```py
 #!/usr/bin/env python

'''
        "arg" is a string or None
        if "arg" is None : the terminal is reset to his default values.
        if "arg" is a string it must contain "sep" separated values.
        if args are found in globals "attrs" or "colors", or start with "@" \
    they are interpreted as ANSI commands else they are output as text.
        @* commands:

            @x;y : go to xy
            @    : go to 1;1
            @@   : clear screen and go to 1;1
        @[colour] : set foreground colour
        ^[colour] : set background colour

        examples:
    echo('@red')                  : set red as the foreground color
    echo('@red ^blue')             : red on blue
    echo('@red @blink')            : blinking red
    echo()                       : restore terminal default values
    echo('@reverse')              : swap default colors
    echo('^cyan @blue reverse')    : blue on cyan <=> echo('blue cyan)
    echo('@red @reverse')          : a way to set up the background only
    echo('@red @reverse @blink')    : you can specify any combinaison of \
            attributes in any order with or without colors
    echo('@blink Python')         : output a blinking 'Python'
    echo('@@ hello')             : clear the screen and print 'hello' at 1;1

colours:
{'blue': 4, 'grey': 0, 'yellow': 3, 'green': 2, 'cyan': 6, 'magenta': 5, 'white': 7, 'red': 1}



    '''

'''
    Set ANSI Terminal Color and Attributes.
'''
from sys import stdout
import random
import sys
import time

esc = '%s['%chr(27)
reset = '%s0m'%esc
format = '1;%dm'
fgoffset, bgoffset = 30, 40
for k, v in dict(
    attrs = 'none bold faint italic underline blink fast reverse concealed',
    colours = 'grey red green yellow blue magenta cyan white'
).items(): globals()[k]=dict((s,i) for i,s in enumerate(v.split()))
bpoints = ( " [*] ", " [!] ", )

def echo(arg=None, sep=' ', end='\n', rndcase=True, txtspeed=0.03, bnum=0):

    cmd, txt = [reset], []
    if arg:
            if bnum != 0:
                    sys.stdout.write(bpoints[bnum-1])

        # split the line up into 'sep' seperated values - arglist
            arglist=arg.split(sep)

        # cycle through arglist - word seperated list 
            for word in arglist:

                if word.startswith('@'):
            ### First check for a colour command next if deals with position ###
                # go through each fg and bg colour  
                tmpword = word[1:]
                    if tmpword in colours:
                        cmd.append(format % (colours[tmpword]+fgoffset))
                    c=format % attrs[tmpword] if tmpword in attrs else None
                    if c and c not in cmd:
                                cmd.append(c)
                    stdout.write(esc.join(cmd))
                    continue
                # positioning (starts with @)
                word=word[1:]
                if word=='@':
                    cmd.append('2J')
                    cmd.append('H')
                    stdout.write(esc.join(cmd))
                    continue
                else:
                    cmd.append('%sH'%word)
                    stdout.write(esc.join(cmd))
                    continue

                if word.startswith('^'):
            ### First check for a colour command next if deals with position ###
                # go through each fg and bg colour  
                tmpword = word[1:]
                    if tmpword in colours:
                        cmd.append(format % (colours[tmpword]+bgoffset))
                    c=format % attrs[tmpword] if tmpword in attrs else None
                    if c and c not in cmd:
                                cmd.append(c)
                    stdout.write(esc.join(cmd))
                    continue                    
            else:
                for x in word:  
                    if rndcase:
                        # thankyou mark!
                        if random.randint(0,1):
                                x = x.upper()
                        else:
                            x = x.lower()
                    stdout.write(x)
                    stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(txtspeed)
                stdout.write(' ')
                time.sleep(txtspeed)
    if txt and end: txt[-1]+=end
    stdout.write(esc.join(cmd)+sep.join(txt))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    echo('@@') # clear screen
    #echo('@reverse') # attrs are ahem not working
    print 'default colors at 1;1 on a cleared screen'
    echo('@red hello this is red')
    echo('@blue this is blue @red i can ^blue change @yellow blah @cyan the colours in ^default the text string')
    print
    echo()
    echo('default')
    echo('@cyan ^blue cyan blue')
    print
    echo()
    echo('@cyan this text has a bullet point',bnum=1)
    print
    echo('@yellow this yellow text has another bullet point',bnum=2)
    print
    echo('@blue this blue text has a bullet point and no random case',bnum=1,rndcase=False)
    print
    echo('@red this red text has no bullet point, no random case and no typing effect',txtspeed=0,bnum=0,rndcase=False)
#   echo('@blue ^cyan blue cyan')
    #echo('@red @reverse red reverse')
#    echo('yellow red yellow on red 1')
#    echo('yellow,red,yellow on red 2', sep=',')
#    print 'yellow on red 3'

#        for bg in colours:
#                echo(bg.title().center(8), sep='.', end='')
#                for fg in colours:
#                        att=[fg, bg]
#                        if fg==bg: att.append('blink')
#                        att.append(fg.center(8))
#                        echo(','.join(att), sep=',', end='')

    #for att in attrs:
    #   echo('%s,%s' % (att, att.title().center(10)), sep=',', end='')
    #   print

    from time import sleep, strftime, gmtime
    colist='@grey @blue @cyan @white @cyan @blue'.split()
    while True:
        try:
            for c in colist:
                sleep(.1)
                echo('%s @28;33 hit ctrl-c to quit' % c,txtspeed=0)
                echo('%s @29;33 hit ctrl-c to quit' % c,rndcase=False,txtspeed=0)
            #echo('@yellow @6;66 %s' % strftime('%H:%M:%S', gmtime()))
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
        except:
            raise
    echo('@10;1')
    print
```

should also mention that i have absolutely no idea what this line does :) - well i see that it puts colours into a dictionary object, but how it does it is confusing. not used to this python syntax yet.

```
for k, v in dict(
    attrs = 'none bold faint italic underline blink fast reverse concealed',
    colours = 'grey red green yellow blue magenta cyan white'
).items(): globals()[k]=dict((s,i) for i,s in enumerate(v.split()))
```

Comment: To insert special characters inside a Python string, you can just scape then with "\xHH" where HH is the hex of the character code. Thus, no need to do `esc = '%s['%chr(27)`  - just `esc = '\x1b' `does the trick

Comment: ah ok, ill change that bit, thankyou. im thinking of this as an all round txt effects type module, perhaps i should rethink it in a class, not that i know how to do a class, but ill figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather convoluted code - but, sticking to you r question, about the lines:

`cmd.append(format % (colours[tmpword]+fgoffset))`

This expression appends to the list named `cmd` the interpolation of the string contained in the variable `format` with the result of the expression `(colours[tmpword]+fgoffset))`- which concatenates the code in the color table (colours) named by `tmpword` with `fgoffset`.

The `format` string contains  `'1;%dm'` which means it expects an integer number, whcih will replace the "%d" inside it. (Python's `%` string substitution inherits from C's printf formatting) . You "colours" color table  ont he other hand is built in a convoluted way I'd recomend in no code, setting directly the entry in "globals" for it - but let's assume it does have the correct numeric value for each color entry. In that case, adding it to `fgoffset` will generate color codes out of range (IRCC, above 15) for some color codes and offsets.

Now the second line in which you are in doubt:

`c=format % attrs[tmpword] if tmpword in attrs else None`

This `if` is just Python's ternary operator - equivalent to the C'ish `expr?:val1: val2`

It is equivalent to:

if tmpword in attrs:
   c = format % attrs[tmpword]
else:
   c = format % None

Note that it has less precedence than the `%` operator.
Maybe you would prefer:

`c= (format % attrs[tmpword]) if tmpword in attrs else  ''`

instead

Comment: hey! thanks a lot! thats really cleared up a lot for me. yes, its kind of working but it was an ugly hack which im trying to make better. i should mention im a total beginner and im trying to make sense of all this stuff.  i dont understand what you mean about the colour table built in a convoluted way ? any improvements much appreciated. oh and i put a print out of the colour table with its numbers in the comments, just to check the nums are ok. it seems to work.

Comment: As for the  "convoluted way" - in Python we prise readability a lot, and as part of that, modifying the dictionary returned by "globals()" should be done just in extreme cases - so, one example to simplify the  start of your code is to replace the `for k, v in dict( ... enumerate(v.split()))` line with these 2 lines: `attrs = dict ((name, val) for val, name in enumerate('none bold faint italic underline blink fast reverse concealed' .split()))` and `colours =  dict((name, val) for val, name in enumerate('grey red green yellow blue magenta cyan white' .split()))`

Comment: ok ill put that in, trying to convert it to a class at the moment. thanks again dude.